# tce api tollcost.json returns no costs

Tags: here-api

For example this url returns no costs:

```
https://tce.api.here.com/2/tollcost.json?app_id=xxxx&app_code=xxxx&tollVehicleType=3&rollup=country&currency=EUR&route=-1201736915;-1126692456
```

Here's the response:

```
{"errors":[],"warnings":[],"costsByCountry":[],"onError":false}
```

If instead using the the fleet api calculateroute.json with the same coordinates:

```
https://fleet.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?app_id=xxxx&app_code=yyyy&waypoint0=49.45276,8.51315&detail=1&waypoint1=46.18977,6.24859&routelegattributes=none&routeattributes=none&maneuverattributes=none&linkattributes=none&legattributes=none&currency=EUR&tollVehicleType=3&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&rollups=country&alternatives=0
```

The response contains cost 93.89€:

```
"cost":{"totalCost":"93.89","currency":"EUR","details":{"driverCost":"0.0","vehicleCost":"0.0","tollCost":"93.89","optionalValue":0.0}}
```

Shouldn't both apis return the same cost?

Answer (score 0):

HERE API provides two APIs one is to calculate [toll cost optimised route](https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/cost_optimized_route) using toll cost extension services and second one to get the [route with Toll cost](https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/route_with_tce).

Here is the [link](https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/dev_guide/topics/examples.html) for the documentation

Hope this helps.

Comment: I must say it's a bit confusing, I find calculateroute.json in these 3 apis: route.api, fleet.api and tce.api. We currently use route.api for routing and would now like to get toll costs also. The tce.api gets similar distances as the route.api while fleet.api can get quite much longer distances, we send similar vehicle parameters to all 3 apis when testing. So we would probably like to use tce.api to get similar distances as we get now with route.api, but is it still supported or is it obsolete? I cannot find any documentation for it other than a pdf and that first example you sent.